# Makefile can't find file in same directory

Tags: c++, c, unix, makefile

Okay so here is my current directory `arch.c archmake.c archsearch.c rearch.c makefile in.txt`

The error I'm getting is `'ake: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target 'arch.c`

And here is my makefile

```
prog: arch.o archmake.o archsearch.o rearch.o
    gcc arch.o archmake.o archsearch.o rearch.o -o prog
arch.o: arch.c
    gcc -c arch.c
archmake.o: archmake.c
    gcc -c archmake.c
archsearch.o: archsearch.c
    gcc -c archsearch.c
rearch.o: rearch.c
    gcc -c rearch.c
```

I am at a loss I feel like ever thing is spelled out. Every thing compiles and works if I type out the commands and don't use the make file.

Comment: Please include the error message in the question itself.

Comment: Images and links to images in questions is one of the most effective ways to accrue downvotes. I recommend against using them.

Comment: Okay thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error message *very* closely.  The file name listed at the end of the line is

```
`arch.c
```

with an unmatched quote.  At the beginning of the line is another quote.  I suspect your file is actually named `arch.c^M`, with the last character being a 'carriage-return' character.  Try listing the contents of the directory with `ls -b`.

If so, then you can rename the file with

```
mv arch.c* tmp
mv tmp arch.c
```

Comment: Perhaps there's a `^M` in the makefile?

Comment: Yeah, that error is in the makefile not the actual filename.

Comment: So how would I go about seeing or removing the ^M? The makefile in this post is how it looks in my editor (sublime text 2) but I have a return after the last line. I get a different error if I don't have the return. if I get rid of the enter on the last line it give "mksh: Warning: newline is not last character in file makefile Current working directory ~~~~~mydir~~~~~ 'ake: Fatal error: Don't know how to make target `arch.c"

Comment: In that case, it sounds as if you have a pretty common line-ending problem.  Your Makefile lines are (probably) terminated by CR-LF, while `make` expects them to be terminated by just LF and (rather unhelpfully/stupidly) it's regarding the ‘extra’ `CR` as a character in the filename and not as whitespace (this sounds like a slightly weird setup, by the way). How to fix this will depend on what text file editor you're using, and what platform, but is a pretty common problem which you'll surely be able to search for advice on, now you at least suspect what the problem is.